# Error MSB4113: Specified condition "$(AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings)" evaluates to " True " instead of a boolean

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, azure-devops

I'm getting this error when adding an existing project to VSTS:

> Error MSB4113: Specified condition
>   "$(AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings)" evaluates to "
>   True " instead of a boolean.

The project compiles and runs fine locally.  I can see that the AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings is in the .csproj file and appears to be set correctly:

```
<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
  True
</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
```

I've tried changing it to `true`, `1` and `-1`, but as you'd expect, that didn't fix it. What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out the error message does actually explain the issue, it's just very easy to miss that it's saying "[space]True[space]".  In other words, the issue is caused by the spacing around the `True` in the .csproj file.

Changing the declaration to

```
<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>True</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
```

(i.e. all on one line) fixes it.

Comment: Microsoft seems to be the culprit since [there's white space in the docs](http://web.archive.org/web/20140424060129/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/dd465342(v=vs.100).aspx). I submitted feedback that it breaks the build, so hopefully they'll correct it.